Safe connector with wagmi library
We have recently been adding safe as a wallet option into our application. We have multiple connection options, including, metamask, wallet connect, coinbase wallet. All of these work fine. We use wagmi to create those connectors. Connecting to safe through wallet connect also works.
However, we have a little problem with waiting from the transaction result, if there are at least two signers required for a safe multisig. The transaction hash that gets simulated by wagmi is the hash of the first signature, not the actual execution of the transaction in the second. We wait on the confirmation of the transaction to trigger some changes in our app. Therefore, we have here the problem of waiting for the "wrong" transaction since the hash where the execution happens is not the one we can simulate at first.
I recently saw that safe is also listed as a standalone connector by wagmi, and thought that this might solve our problem, in addition to integrating deeper with the safe SDK.
However, we get an error when trying to connect
Provider not found. Version: @wagmi/core@2.6.10

What is really strange is that the example https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/main/examples/wagmi also triggers the same error.
Has anyone managed to make this connector work?

are you using vite to bundle your assets ?

No, it's a simple nextJS setup

Thanks for your question!
Here are some suggestions to help you get unblocked:
1. Use the Transaction Status to Check Execution
When you propose a transaction on the Safe Smart Account, it receives a unique safeTxHash. While this differs from the final transaction hash, you can use the safeTxHash to monitor the transaction's status. By polling the status, you can wait for the isExecuted boolean to return true, indicating that the transaction has been executed.
To query the API, you have two options:

Send a request directly to the Get Multisig Transaction endpoint.
Use the Safe{Core} API Kit with the getTransaction function.

2. Use the Correct Transaction Hash to Await Execution
The API call mentioned above will also return the transaction hash once the transaction has been sent to the blockchain. You can use this transaction hash with wagmi to await the transaction's execution.
3. Use the Safe{Core} Protocol Kit to Await the Transaction
If your dapp supports it, you can use the Safe{Core} Protocol Kit to execute and await the transaction directly. The executeTransaction method is specifically designed for this purpose.
4. Wait for Us to Fix the Wagmi Safe Connector Example
Thanks for pointing out that the example isn't working as expected. We've tested it internally and will address the issue, though it may take some time as it's not our highest priority at the moment.
Let me know if this solves your problem (and mark the question as answered) or if you encounter further issues.

Thank you for your answer! In the meantime, we actually ended up using what you mentioned in 1.1, since we need to get the future transaction hash from there. We then store it and check periodically in our backend when the transaction has been executed, and we then perform some offchain actions.

Great you came to the same conclusion! So you found it more convenient to use the API directly instead of using the Api Kit? Let us know if you encounter further issues.

Yes, tbh we got a bit confused with the API kit, the core kit, the wallet kit, etc. We haven't found a good page to distinguishes which is which.
We saw that this endpoint would answer our problem and so we decided to use it. (It also means that it keeps our app lighter since no need to import anything.)

Thank you very much for the valuable feedback! Very much appreciated.
